# Does anyone have the monokai theme for PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

**I really miss the monokai theme**!!! and really can't stand the white background.

[image]

Does anyone have a PyCharm schema for monokai by chance? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Here you go](http://www.monokai.nl/blog/2006/07/15/textmate-color-theme/)** =)

[This guy](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290448;jsessionid=056F757BF91DDBB6EB2686486B2B1FB0) has started porting the schema to PyCharm. See the 2nd post and the attached file.

Comment: How do I use that xml file?

Comment: Seems like one now has to "pay for a license" to use it. I.e this question could use a new alternative answer, with the same syntax coloring.

Answer (score 3):

In PyCharm 3.x, Monokai scheme is bundled. So you can easily find it in Settings.

Comment: It's bundled even in PyCharm 2.

Comment: Hah, I didn't use it back then. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's *almost* like Sublime's Monokai, but the only thing that is really annoying me is that keywords `for` are grouped together with built-in functions such as `enumerate` (both are light blue), whereas in Sublime 3 the keywords are red and the built-in functions light blue only. Any idea on how to set it as such in PyCharm?

Comment: To set the Monokai theme, 
Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme Font